# Challenges with Setting the Number of Times Each Agent Enters the System per Month

Tags: simulation, anylogic

The problem lies in the setup of the agent. I am calling a function, on the setup property of the "client" agent to set the number of visits per month for each agent. It works fine.

[image]
When I use variables to define different memberships, such as `if (diamond == true) {visits per month = triangular(10,15)}`, it doesn't work as intended, the visit per month was not set, and no agent left eventually.

[image]

I have multiple sources, and upon entering each source, I set a specific membership type to true, as shown in the attached image. **I thought the issue was arising because the function that sets the monthly visits is called before the variable determining the membership type becomes true.**

[image]

**So, what I did was,** once all the agents were injected and a specific membership variable became true for them, I called the **setVisitsPerMonth** function. However, the "visitPerMonth" variable is still null for all the agents.

[image]

When I remove the condition 'Diamond == true' or 'Platinum == true' from the **setVisitsPerMonth** function, then the "visitPerMonth" variable gets assigned values.

Let me know if you need any further information in order to help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set your visits per month in the source right after defining their boolean values.

Background: You are reaching some intricacies of AnyLogic and the sequence of how code is executed :)

Comment: Actually, I have an event in the **client** Agent that has this code: `main.enter.take(main.queue.remove(this));` `event.restart(30 / visitsPerMonth, DAY);` This event frees the agent from the queue and restarts itself based on the number of visits. The number of times the agent visits is equally divided among the 30 days.

Comment: best revise the original question then, hard to follow :)